# How to Convert Text on a JTextArea to acsii binary and back on java

Tags: java, binary, ascii, converters

I am writing code to make a converter for text to binary. i used this.

```
public static void BinaryConverter() {

    String string = Window.TextArea.getText();  

    byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();


    System.out.println(string + "=" + bytes);

}
```

I then get this in the console.

=[B@79e7c7fb

Comment: You should show us what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to use `String#getBytes()` to get the underlying bytes and then present those bytes in some other form (hex, binary whatever).

Note that `getBytes()` uses the default charset, so if you want the string converted to some specific character encoding, you should use `getBytes(String encoding)` instead, but many times (esp when dealing with ASCII) `getBytes()` is enough (and has the advantage of not throwing a checked exception).

For specific conversion to binary, here is an example:

```
  String s = "foo";
  byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
  StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
  for (byte b : bytes)
  {
     int val = b;
     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     {
        binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        val <<= 1;
     }
     binary.append(' ');
  }
  System.out.println("'" + s + "' to binary: " + binary);
```

Running this example will yield:

```
'foo' to binary: 01100110 01101111 01101111
```